# Populate Winforms treeview with Sharepoint site

Tags: winforms, sharepoint, treeview, populate

I'm very new to sharepoint and I have to a task with it.

I have my site adress but just about it.

I need to populate a treeview with all the hierarchy from SPSite and down for my sharepoint site using C#;

I guess I need to use recursive functions to do so...

can anyone help?

thank you.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? And are you developing a custom web part for navigation? Do you want to mimic the OOTB Tree View navigation already available? Please be more clear as to what you are trying to achieve, where, and why.

Comment: Sharepoint 2013. the tree is already available, there are some directories and some files. I wanna achive a tree that will be good even if i'm gonna add more files or even library under library.            thank you fot you're help.

Comment: I am not developing a custom web part, I need to do it in winforms
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

public void FillTreeSPWeb(SPWeb MySPWeb, TreeNode Node, int num)
        {

```
         if (num <= 0)
            {
            Node.Text = MySPWeb.Title;
            GetSPDocumentLibrary(MySPWeb, Node);
            }

            num--;



        foreach (SPWeb item in MySPWeb.Webs)
        {              
            TreeNode Child = new TreeNode();
            FillTreeSPWeb(item, Child,num);
            Node.Nodes.Add(Child);

        }

    }

    public void GetSPDocumentLibrary(SPWeb MySPWeb,TreeNode Node)
    {
        foreach (SPList item1 in MySPWeb.Lists)
        {

            if (item1.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
            {
                SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)item1;


                try
                {
                    TreeNode Child = new TreeNode(oDocumentLibrary.Title);

                    GetFiles(oDocumentLibrary.RootFolder, Child);
                    foreach (SPListItem item in oDocumentLibrary.Folders)
                    {

                        TreeNode GrandChild = new TreeNode();
                        FillFilesAndFolders(item.Folder, GrandChild);

                        Child.Nodes.Add(GrandChild);

                    }
                    Node.Nodes.Add(Child);
                }
                catch { }

            }
        }

    }

    public void FillFilesAndFolders(SPFolder MySPFolder, TreeNode Node)
    {
        Node.Text = MySPFolder.Name;


        GetFiles(MySPFolder, Node);


        foreach (SPFolder item1 in MySPFolder.SubFolders)
        {                
            FillFilesAndFolders(item1, Node);               
        }

    }

    public void GetFiles(SPFolder MySPFolder,TreeNode Node)
    {

        foreach (SPFile item in MySPFolder.Files)
        {

            Node.Nodes.Add(item.Name);

        }
    }
```